# Sorting by Date After Mult-IMPORTRANGE and QUERY

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, spreadsheet, formulas

Have a Google Sheet that I'm trying to build. It uses IFTTT to pull articles people read into a individual, and then an aggregate spreadsheet.

**In terms of specs, it needs to:**

Pull in data from multiple sheets.

The first column in each source sheet is a date column.  Some are formulas (to remove extraneous data from another date column), and some are hard-coded.  This may differ sheet to sheet, but is constant per sheet.

Once imported into the aggregate sheet, I need to sort by date.

**Problem**
I'm a query/importrange newbie, and I'm currently stuck on the sorting by date.

Current URL

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GLGYvApJgRheg7rgzoB8rFyTUgkRpZ2O8eKVE4bZyo4/edit?usp=sharing

When I order by Col1, I can't honestly tell how it is sorting, the end result is:

March 7, 2017
February 15, 2007
February 28, 2017
March 7, 2017
March 8, 2017
November 9, 2010

If you inspect the cells, the first March 7, 2017 is situated where the formula resides, which does not seem to move no matter how I sort.  If you look at the sort order without that cell, it seems to be sorting alphabetically.

**So it comes down to two main questions:**

-What am I doing wrong that is making it so the order by is not including the first row. 
**Edit: This is now fixed**

-How do I get it to recognize that the contents of the sorting column is a date?

Thanks ahead of time - 
J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula seems to have a few problems.

1. `importrange` should take `key` not `url`. But it seems that it works anyway...
2. Pulled sheets have no header, so the 3rd parameter of `query` should be `-1` or omitted, not `1`.
3. If `Col1` is a *valid* date, `<> ''` should not work. It should be `is not null`.
4. But it turns out that your pulled sheets' dates are not `yyyy-mm-dd` format so they weren't recognized as dates by `query`.

Thus, more valid formula should be like this:

```
=query({importrange("...", "Sheet1!A:E");importrange("...", "Sheet1!A:E")}, 
 "select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1 asc",
 -1)
```

And you should format dates(column A) on your pulled sheets to `yyyy-mm-dd`. Check my working sample [aggregator](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jud06LdfgLhaEXnNm3a2kCVIr0RG9kjlWInT1TRSEVs/) and pulled sheet [one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17JI7T98JsKIlrCbKrNZwr7rDXHVizee7E0k36SY2q9o/) and [two](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hEvzBNykU6Cov9mpk8bdexePM7ctlj6tFKScENB8Y2g/edit#gid=0).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!
I switched to key, which doesn't seem to impact it, but if it's the right way, it's fixed.
The -1 query fixes the "sticky" row occupied by the formula.  
Adding not null makes all of my entries disappear.  I've granted you access to the source sheet I think is the problem, which has formula based dates.  Yours worked, but i noticed they are hardcoded.  I've saved a second sheet in the aggregator with not null as the selection criteria.

Comment: Just noticed they don't disappear on the second sheet, rather get pushed to row 1993.  They are still sorted alphabetically.  So basically I just need to figure out how to have the column sort as a date.

Comment: My mistake, `is not null` is wrong, it should be `<> ''`. I edited the answer, and I modified the sample aggregator to import your file 'Jer's Tech Feed'.

Comment: Thank you again for the help.  I added in the second sheet to your copy, and as I'm sure you can see it's sorting alphabetically, as opposed to chronologically.  Is there any way to fix this?  Defining the sort column data type as a date or something along those lines?

Comment: It turns out that your pulled sheets' dates are not `yyyy-mm-dd` format so it cannot be recognized as a date by query. You should format dates(column A) on your pulled sheets to `yyyy-mm-dd`. Check sample sheet again.

Comment: Great! So basically its just date formatting.  The main problem I see is that These articles are being fed in from another service, and I'm using a formula to strip out the timestamp.  Is there any way to apply this formatting to a formula result?  When I try and change it on my sheet it maintains the format of the output of the formula, rather than the number formatting.  Formula is =TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(E1," at .*M","")) against the cell contents Date Month, Year at Time (AM/PM).

Comment: You can use `datevalue()` to convert string to date automatically like `=datevalue(trim(regexreplace(E1," at .*M","")))`. Check my sample pulled sheet two.

Comment: Merged your formulas into my sheets, and it looks like it is working now!  감사합니다